# Are we trying to be an encyclopedia for sports questions?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So let's say I have a sports related question and if I do a little bit of searching online I can find the question and the answer on some other website. Do we want such questions on SE?

In one hand it's not really necessary or useful to post a question that already exists on the internet? But on the other hand SE needs more promotion and by posting such questions we can get more hits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ben Miller points this out in [his answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/698) for another meta question. Emphasis mine to address your question.

> Having basic questions with great answers does not hurt our site at
>   all, in my opinion.  In fact, **the stated goal of our website**, as
>   expressed on our [Tour page](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tour), **is**
>   this:
>
> > With your help, we're working together **to build a library of detailed answers to every question about sports**.
>
> Just because the answer can be found elsewhere doesn't mean that we
>   shouldn't also have the answer here

So, if "build[ing] a library of detailed answers to every question about sports" is equivalent to "trying to be an encyclopedia for sports questions," then yes, that's what we're doing/trying to be based on the verbiage presented on our own tour page.