# If you put effort into answering a question, it's probably worth an upvote

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I've started thinking that our site's users need to be a little bit more generous long before, but after [this Question about the best loser](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16853/question-about-the-best-loser) from a new user gathered **5 answers and only 1 upvote** (by the time of publishing) I got really upset.

This issue was already discussed in [other communities](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/if-a-question-is-worth-answering-its-probably-worth-upvoting) and the general idea is that:

> - If you feel the question is worth answering, you should give it an upvote too.
> - Upvote good questions and answers, and consider downvoting bad questions and answers too (although maybe not for brand new users - we
>     don't want to scare them off).
> - **The number of up votes on a question should always be greater than or equal to the number of answers provided by the community.**

The last one is called Gayot's Postulate ([Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow) is the name of the user who proposed it). So, if you see a question where the Postulate has failed, please consider upvoting it to maintain balance in the force.

Again, I encourage everyone to read [the original post on Travel SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/if-a-question-is-worth-answering-its-probably-worth-upvoting).

Comment: [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/)!!

Comment: We have the same problem everywhere around the network. too much low level user that don´t know how the site work.

Comment: @gbianchi, I wouldn't open this thread if it were only new users.

Comment: Totally agree!  My biggest pet peeve is when I see users (especially high rep users) answering a question and then the question sits there with no upvotes.  If you are putting in the effort to answer a question, then you obviously thought that the question was interesting and worthy of your time.  So upvote it! :)

Answer (score 3):

> If you put effort into answering a question, it's probably worth an upvote

I'm going to disagree.

If you put effort into answering a question, it's probably because you have an answer. Nothing more, nothing less.

I looked at the [vote up privilege](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up):

> **What is voting up?**
>
> Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers
>   are most useful and appropriate.
>
> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is
>   especially useful, vote it up!

Full disclosure: I haven't voted on any posts (yet). Not voting seems against the status quo, but I do understand why voting is essential (as indirectly addressed later in this post). I'll gladly accept being chewed out for my lack of participation.

For the questions I have answered, it is simply because I could provide an answer. I didn't consider voting up while providing answers because my ability to provide an answer doesn't correlate to thinking the question is useful. Voting a question up because an answer can be provided seems to circumvent the purpose of the voting system, [which is](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/829/if-you-put-effort-into-answering-a-question-its-probably-worth-an-upvote#comment1812_829):

> Putting voting front and center is very much intentional; it is how …
>
> - good content is voted to the top
> - wrong or incorrect content is voted to the bottom
> - users who consistently provide useful content accrue reputation and
>     are granted more privileges on the site

My answering a question shouldn't be a reflection on the question itself (whether the question is good, bad, easy, hard, inhumane, whatever). Multiple answers on a question that is considered off-topic doesn't necessarily mean the question is on-topic. The fact the question can have answers is essential on a Q&A-focused site, as highlighted in [this comment](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia#comment73_45):

> The more objectively [a question] can be answered, the BETTER it fits the model.

Ultimately, I understand voting, being generous to new users and the ilk, but being upset and "maintaining balance in the force" are overreactions. **If the question is "most useful and appropriate," it will earn the respect it deserves.** This question with 5 answers and 1 point deserves this spotlight, but disagree with why this question got this spotlight (upvote the question because you have an answer).

**My point: Questions and answers should be treated as standalone entities and voted upon individually toward its being "most useful and appropriate."**

Comment: Well said. It doesn't feel right to upvote a bad question only because you answered it. And not answering a bad question is kinda bad too (if you know the answer and it's not just a LMGTFY question), only because you don't want to upvote it.

Comment: @dly I feel the same way. However, I saw that answering bad questions is [encouraging low quality](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/697). Would you say that is or should be the case? I don't see what's wrong with answering a "bad" question (if you have an answer for it) **AND** voting down on the question (if it is, in fact, that bad).

Comment: That's a difficult one and pretty much depends on each question itself. I'd always try to answer a "valid" question, if possible. However, I can understand the point in not answering too basic questions (which can as well be googled in 5 seconds). Depending on my mood and how stupid that question really is (like "why are there two goals on a football pitch") I'd just downvote or answer and downvote them.

Comment: @dly just an FYI, [your answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/18006) to a question further reinforces my point. [Where (and how) to buy tickets](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/american-buying-ac-milan-tickets) appear to be off topic here, but since you provided an adequate answer, the question is being received well.

Comment: The older question seeks recommendation while the newer one explicitly asks about ticket availability at the stadium. I don't agree that this question meets the requirement to be off-topic for "shopping recommendation".

Comment: @dly I see your point. The reason I note this because I recall seeing a close reason for a similar question along the lines of "we are not customer support" and I saw the question from a similar perspective.

Comment: Found the question with the "customer service" close reason: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13885/can-euro-2016-tickets-be-transferred-to-a-someone