# Are questions specifically asking about trivial illegal situations without being about rules allowed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/22377/throw-in-directly-into-the-goal) is asking about throw-ins thrown directly into a goal. Deflections or any other situations are not "allowed". So everything that would make it actually notable is ruled out.

In this case the situation is

- very trivial, because it's just a simple call by the ref and no statistics are being recorded either and
- not about a specific situation (too broad) and
- always against the IFAB Laws, because everything that would make it useful is not wanted as an answer.

I see no use in keeping a question like that, because of the reasons mentioned above.

Am I right or is this question still good enough?

Answer (score 2):

It's not illegal though. It just can't score a goal. This is an important distinction in sports officiating that many people struggle with, including perhaps yourself (given the title used and the third bullet point).

For football at least, laws of the game are relevant and this question is about the rules applying, to the specific situation of a throw-in directly entering the goal.

It's less trivial than a number of other questions we've deemed *acceptable* (in the sense that they remain open, answered, not heavily downvoted) in the past few months.

Finally, see [the previous meta discussion on this same topic](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/661/rules-questions-with-little-effort-do-we-close-these-questions-as-off-topic-o). The community consensus is that such questions are on-topic, if for no other reason than that they're just not off-topic.

Comment: The linked Meta doesn't address the issue as it's not about rules. The OP wants to know occurrences a certain situation *already knowing that it's against the rules*. I already tried to answer that and got slapped in my face for it, because the question wasn't clear enough (a lot of comments addressing this issue are deleted by now, pretty much because I got tired of discussing it on the main site). This question is like "how many times did Cristiano Ronaldo stand in an offside position?" without mentioning a time span or league/club.

Comment: But it **is not** against the rules. Players can throw it in directly to the goal all day long, they cannot ever be penalised for it.

Comment: It may not be illegal to throw there, but it is illegal to score a goal directly from a throw-in. That's different. The penalty is the goal being disallowed.

Comment: That's not correct, either. It isn't *illegal* to score a goal directly from a throw-in; it simply *can't be done at all*. This is in contrast to the scoring of a goal using the hand or arm after the 2019 changes, which *is* illegal and penalised as hand-ball.

Comment: Regardless of how you word it, the goal won't count and the original question is not about the rules (or laws) either, so this answer still doesn't fully address the issue.

Comment: But that question is asking about an evidently rare situation and whether it has actually happened at the top level. That goes directly to why such a rule even exists, and is still entirely on-topic.